# Bounty hunter's track purgeable?

Tags: dota-2

I just started playing dota 2 now and I play BH a lot and I usually play as divine rapier carry. So I want to know if His ulti Track is purge-able using any spell?

Comment: The purpose of the question body isn't to reiterate your title, but to add details to explain your question.

Comment: @Vemonus Sometimes a question needs no more details. Although it's usually not a very good question in those cases, because it tends to be easily looked up.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I understand, but even just providing some background info like why someone would want to know or what prompted the question would probably get better reception.

Comment: Edited given background

Comment: I really don't see how the background helps in any way in this case, TBH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be removed with basic dispels. I suggest you look at the Dota 2 wiki for information like this, for example the [Dispel page](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dispel).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be purged through basic dispels. In case you are not aware what is a dispel, stone examples of it are Legion Commander's 2nd skill,
Slark's 1st skill, difussal blade, etc.

You can also purge slardar's ultimate through dispel.

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer, and you're basically just repeating what I've already said. Try not to do that.

Comment: I am not repeating @DanmakuGrazer, I am adding.

Comment: Yes, you are repeating. Adding information that doesn't matter is not valuable.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Sir How do you expect that everyone knows what a dispel is

Comment: The OP mentioned purge, so he knows what dispels are. In case he doesn't, I also provided a link to the wiki, which is perfect for this. As for your examples, you gave two strong dispels (not basic), and one that can't even purge allies anymore.